# ConTeXt problems with custom start-stop for tabulate

Tags: environments, context

In my document, I have several instances of a tabulate environment, all of which look like this:

```
\startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
  \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
    \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
    % --- varying content here, example line: ---
    \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
    % -------------------------------------------
    \HL
  \stoptabulate
\stopplacetable
```

So I try to create a custom start-stop environment:

```
\definestartstop[ProcessTable][
  before={%
    \startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
      \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
        \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
    },%
  after={%
        \HL
      \stoptabulate
    \stopplacetable
  }%
]
```

This, when used in a document, never finishes, e.g.:

```
\starttext
  \startProcessTable
    \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \stopProcessTable
\stoptext
```

last two lines of ConTeXt output:

```
close source    > level 2, order 3, name '/.../test.tex'
close source    > level 1, order 3, name '/usr/local/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-yes.mkiv'
```

When trying to use it together with the original code:

```
\starttext
  \startProcessTable
    \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \stopProcessTable

  \startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
    \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
      \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
    \stoptabulate
  \stopplacetable
\stoptext
```

I get this output which hints to something being seriously wrong:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 34 in file /.../test.tex: ! Missing } inserted

<inserted text>
}
<to be read again>
\endtemplate
<template> \endtemplate

\tabl_tabulate_column_normal ...\unskip \aligntab
                                                  \ifconditional \c_tabl_tab...
\tabl_tabulate_insert_body ...\dotagconstruct \NC
                                                  A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \...
\tabl_tabulate_insert_content ...late_insert_body
                                                  \tabl_tabulate_insert_foot...
...
l.34     \stoptabulate


24     %]
25
26     \starttext
27       \startProcessTable
28         \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
29       \stopProcessTable
30
31       \startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
32         \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
33           \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
34 >>      \stoptabulate
35       \stopplacetable
36     \stoptext
```

While trying to solve this, I discovered that there is `\definetabulate`, so I tried to use that instead:

```
\definetabulate[ProcessTable][|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
\setuptabulate[ProcessTable][
  before={%
    \startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
  },
  inner={%
    \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
  },
  after={%
    \stopplacetable
  }%
]
```

This compiles, but does not render the table (i.e. the text from both header and body is rendered, but without lines and alignment). I assume that I am using the `inner` parameter wrong, but I found no documentation or example on it. When I remove the `inner` parameter, the table renders, but without the header.

How can I properly setup such an environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `\starttabulate` is looking ahead for `\stoptabulate`, so putting it into `\definestartstop` will not work.  You can work around that by simply collecting the table content as an argument.

```
\unexpanded\long\def\startProcessTable#1\stopProcessTable
  {\startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
    \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
      \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
      #1%
      \HL
    \stoptabulate
  \stopplacetable}

\starttext
  \startProcessTable
    \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \stopProcessTable
\stoptext
```

[image]

If you need to reuse the table content later, or process it in any way, I recommend using buffers:

```
\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\startProcessTable
  {\buff_pickup{ProcessTable}{startProcessTable}{stopProcessTable}{\relax}{\process_table}{\zerocount}}

\unexpanded\def\process_table
  {\startplacetable[location=force,number=no]
    \starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
      \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
      \rawbuffer{ProcessTable}%
      \HL
    \stoptabulate
  \stopplacetable}

\protect

\starttext
  \startProcessTable
    \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \stopProcessTable
\stoptext
```

Comment: To store the content of a environment in a buffer you can use the `\grabbufferdata` command, e.g. `\define\startProcessTable{\grabbufferdata[ProcessTable][startProcessTable][stopProcessTable]}`. To flush the content of the buffer at the end of the environment you can create a custom `stop` command, e.g. `\define\stopProcessTable{\getbufferdata[ProcessTable]}`.

Answer (score 4):

In order for a table to have a specific first and last row, you can use `\starttablehead` and `\starttabletail` (there is a bug in the `tabl-tbl.mkiv`; I'll send a bugfix to the context list, but in the meanwhile, I have included the fix below as well).

```
\starttabulatehead
  \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
\stoptabulatehead

\starttabulatetail
  \HL
\stoptabulatetail

\starttext
\starttabulate[|l|r|rw(2cm)|]
  \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \NC B \NC 400ms \NC 30ms \NC \NR
\stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

However, this adds a head and tail to every table. To apply these to specific tables, we can simply define a new tabulate:

```
\definetabulate[process][|l|r|rw(2cm)|]

\starttabulatehead[process]
  \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
\stoptabulatehead

\starttabulatetail[process]
  \HL
\stoptabulatetail

\starttext
\startprocess
  \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \NC B \NC 400ms \NC 30ms \NC \NR
\stopprocess
\stoptext
```

Now, if you are using a float to center the table, you can add:

```
\setuptabulate
  [process]
  [
    before={\startplacetable[location={force,none}]\insidefloatfalse},
    after={\stopplacetable},
  ]
```

The `\insidefloatfalse` is needed to ensure that `after` key is applied; otherwise, ConTeXt starts in outer mode, applies the before key, and when it is time to apply the after key, it checks that the table is inside a float and does not apply the after key!

So, here is the complete code (with the bugfix for `tabl-tab.mkiv`)

```
\unprotect
\def\tabl_tabulate_check_full_content % - needed, else confusion with \c!header
  {\ifcsname\??tabulatehead\currenttabulation\endcsname
    %\expandafter\ifx\csname\??tabulatehead\currenttabulation\endcsname\empty
     \expandafter\ifx\lastnamedcs\empty
       \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_head\empty
     \else
       \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_head\tabl_tabulate_insert_head_content
     \fi
   \else
     \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_head\empty
   \fi
   \ifcsname\??tabulatefoot\currenttabulation\endcsname
     \expandafter\ifx\csname\??tabulatefoot\currenttabulation\endcsname\empty
    %\expandafter\ifx\lastnamedcs\empty
       \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_foot\empty
     \else
       \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_foot\tabl_tabulate_insert_foot_content
     \fi
   \else
     \let\tabl_tabulate_insert_foot\empty
   \fi}
\protect

\definetabulate[process][|l|r|rw(2cm)|]

\setuptabulate
  [process]
  [
    before={\startplacetable[location={force,none}]\insidefloatfalse},
    after={\stopplacetable},
  ]

\starttabulatehead[process]
  \HL \NC {\bf Process} \NC {\bf\em T} \NC {\bf\em C} \NC \NR \HL
\stoptabulatehead

\starttabulatetail[process]
  \HL
\stoptabulatetail

\starttext

\input knuth

\startprocess
  \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \NC B \NC 400ms \NC 30ms \NC \NR
\stopprocess

\input knuth

\startprocess
  \NC A \NC 200ms \NC 20ms \NC \NR
  \NC B \NC 400ms \NC 30ms \NC \NR
\stopprocess

\input knuth

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]